# Default files in iOS application sandbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I am creating a quiz app for iPhone. I store all the questions in an `NSArray` that is loaded from a `.xml` file every time the app is opened. That file will be the same accross all "instances" of the app, and it will *never* be changed by the user.

I could hard-code all the questions with code, but I found it more elegant to have it in a file that is easily edited by any text editor.

**But how do I give each app "instance" of the app a copy of that file? That file should be bundled along with the rest of the application files.**

This is the code I use so far (in app delegate).

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, 
                                                             YES);
NSString *path = documentPaths[0];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questions.archive"];

NSArray *fileQuestions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (!fileQuestions)
{
    // Code to add three default questions…

    [fileQuestions writeToFile:path
                    atomically:YES];
}

// And here the "file questions" are transformed to instances of my question class
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking *how* to add the xml file as a resource, bundled with the app?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know what it was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to try to store the file in Documents directory. Just store it right there in the app bundle itself. This works exactly like an image file, a sound file, or any other resource. Make the file part of the project; make sure it is part of the *app target*, so that it will be copied into the app bundle as part of the build process. In the running app, get its path with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:]`, and read it as you would any file of this type.

Comment: Tried it and it works perfectly! It's also nice that you can edit the .xml file directly in Xcode with syntax highlighting.